# Django Accessing Session Variable from within Context_Processor function

Tags: django

I am setting a session variable inside my view as:

```
def festival_theme(request, year, month, day, slug):
    festival = Project.objects.get(category__name=__('festival'), slug=slug)

    request.session['_active_festival_id'] = festival.id

    return render(request, 'web/festival/theme.html', {'festival':festival,})
```

than inside my context processor function i want to get this session variable's value. How can i achieve this?

I have tried:

```
#context_processors.py
def festivals(request):
    s = SessionStore()
    activeFestivalId = s['_active_festival_id']
    allFestivals = Project.objects.filter(category__name='festival').order_by('-date')
    return {'allFestivals':allFestivals}
```

Comment: Update the question with your `settings.py`

Comment: Have you also tried simply accessing it like you wrote it? So instead of creating a new `SessionStore` simply use `request.session`?

Comment: Yes i can reach with request.session but context processor initiates before view...  @Burhan : there is no problem with the context_processors in settings.py. I have all the required context_processors and middlewares...

Comment: What could you mean, "context processor initiates before view"? The context processor is called by the template renderer, which is called from the `render` function - ie *inside* your view.

Comment: Ok. Your answer was correct. I have an other problem but it is not related with this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the session by using `request.session` in your context processor.

```
#context_processors.py
def festivals(request):
    activeFestivalId = request.session.get('_active_festival_id', None)
    allFestivals = Project.objects.filter(
        category__name='festival').order_by('-date')
    return {'allFestivals': allFestivals}
```